# Excel select to end of adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

I'm using Excel 2010 on a Mac. If I hit CMD + shift + down arrow, the current column is selected to the end of the column. Is there a keyboard shortcut that, instead of selecting to the end of the column, select up to the end of the data in an adjacent column?

Hopefully this diagram explains what I mean:

[image]

Comment: I would be amazed if there is built in. However, a macro could be work, and also be assigned to a short cut!

Answer (score 6):

In column V1 use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to reach the bottom of the column.

<kbd>→</kbd> across to column W, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to select the column to the top of the cell.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

1. On the cell containing `group1`, Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> once
2. While still holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press the keys to select until the end of the data.
   You write <kbd>⌘</kbd> which is a Mac key and Office 2010 is for Windows. The correct key combination therefore would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. As you are already holding shift, keep it pressed and just additionally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.
3. Now release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so you are only holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and press <kbd>→</kbd> once to get back to the column you want to select.

This should give you the selection you want to have.

Comment: I just tried that in Excel 2013, and there, Ctrl-Shift-Down selects until row 1048576, not the end of the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

This, for Windows system.

Comment: I don't have an `fn` key on my PC. Can you clarify where this information is from and which keys it refers to? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: CMD is the equivalent of Function on an Apple keyboard.  What should be used is Function+Down Arrow this will take the cursor to the last filled cell.

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question. Please read questions thoroughly and do your best to understand what is being asked before answering.